# Simple Click, Query, and Export - not so simple

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can any one help me set up an Access 2007 VBA query where a visually impaired person could enter a date (Pdate) on a form and result in a query of my table [Donation_Data] to find all records with [Pickup Date] = Pdate and then automatically export the records as an EXCEL file.

Here is what I have so far, but stops at

qd.SQL = "SELECT * FROM " & [Donation_Data] & " WHERE [Pickup Date] = Pdate"

```html
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb   ' use current database

'On Error GoTo Pickup_OnClick_Err

Dim Pdate As Date

Pdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Desired Pickup Date", "")


'develop a query of all Donation_Data records where Pickup Date in Donation_Data table = Pdate

Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("DonationDataQuery")

qd.SQL = "SELECT * FROM " & [Donation_Data] & " WHERE [Pickup Date] = Pdate"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "DonationDataQuery", "C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsx", True

Debug.Print qd.SQL

MsgBox "transfered"


End Sub
```

Based on comment recommendation below, code now looks like this.  Query develops beautifully, but no data transfers

```html
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb   ' use current database

'On Error GoTo Pickup_OnClick_Err

Dim Pdate As Date

'Pdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Desired Pickup Date", "")


'develop a query of all Donation_Data records where Pickup Date in Donation_Data table = Pdate

Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("DonationDataQuery")

qd.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Donation_Data] WHERE [Donation_Data].[Pickup Date] = Pdate"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "DonationDataQuery", "C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsm", True

Debug.Print qd.SQL

MsgBox "transfered"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replace the line in question with (UNTESTED):

```
qd.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Donation_Data] WHERE [Donation_Data].[Pickup Date] = Pdate"
```

Comment: Thank you....getting closer.  It creates the query results in Access 2007, but does not transfer any data to the blank file "Donation Data.xlsx."  so I changed the file to Donation Data.xlsm and the statement:

Comment: DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "DonationDataQuery", "C:\Users\dads\Downloads\Donation Data.xlsm", True          transfer message indicates a transfer, but no data in the file

Comment: your inputbox line has an apostrophe infront of it, your SQL has no value for Pdate and thus your code is returning 0 records